# Numpy rank 1 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, rank

I am Matlab/Octave user. Numpy documentation says the `array` is much more advisable to use rather than `matrix`. Is there a convenient way to deal with rank-1 arrays, without reshaping it constantly?

Example:

```
data = np.loadtxt("ex1data1.txt", usecols=(0,1), delimiter=',',dtype=None)
X = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
m = len(y)

print X.shape, y.shape
>>> (97L, ) (97L, )
```

I can't add new column to X using `concatenate`, `vstack`, `append`, except `np.c_` which is slower, without reshaping X:

```
X = np.concatenate((np.ones((m, 1)), X), axis = 1)
>>> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

X - y, couldn't be done without reshaping y `np.reshape(y, (-1, 1))`

Comment: is this question about the concatenation or about rank 1 arrays in general?

Comment: I think about rank 1 arrays in general.

Comment: I use expressions like `np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)` all the time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simpler equivalent to `np.reshape(y, (-1, 1))` is `y[:, np.newaxis]`.  Since `np.newaxis` is an alias for `None`, `y[:, None]` also works.  It's also worth mentioning `np.expand_dims(y, axis=1)`.